# Django append to FileField

Tags: python, django, append, filefield

Is there any way to append directly to a FileField in django? Doing something like this:

```py
class ChunkedUpload(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    data = models.FileField(upload_to='chunked_uploads/')

    def append_chunk(self, chunk, create):
    if create:
        self.data.save(self.id, ContentFile(chunk.encode()))
    else:
        self.data.append(ContentFile(chunk.encode())
```

I'm working on an existing solution that sent data by chunks (base64 encoded string) in TextField. But some data are now too big to be handled in a TextField (250++ Mb). I can't change the other parts of the application, so I'm trying to find a way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Chatbot GPT:

```py
# 1. Create a FileField in your model:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

# 2. Create a function to append to the file:
def append_to_file(file_field, data):
    with open(file_field.path, 'a') as f:
    f.write(data)

# 3. Call the function with the FileField and the data you want to append:
append_to_file(my_model.my_file, 'This is the data I want to append.')
```